# I am not getting values for this influxdb select statement

Tags: influxdb

I am trying to select some values from influxdb datbase. For this below query, the output is null but the values are there.

```
SELECT mean(load1), max(load1) FROM system WHERE  time >= '2016-02-22T09:47:00Z' and time <= '2016-02-22T09:47:00Z'  AND ( host ='daniel-Vostro-2520' ) GROUP BY time(1m);
```

I need to take values between 1 minute from particular time.

What is wrong in the query.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same `time` (2016-02-22T09:47:00Z) defined twice in two different clauses. Nothing will match because you basically defined a time interval of 0.